# Angular 4 omitting HTTP error codes

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have an api call like this:

```
        this.http.get(url)
            .subscribe(results => {
                ...
            }, (err: any) => {
                console.log('raw error =>', err);
        });
```

The error on Chrome shows `502 (Bad Gateway)`, but the error returned from Angular shows `status = 0`, I would like to show message to the user when this error occurs, but how could I  correctly catch the http errors?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, HTTP Status Code 0 is [not really a thing](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10343). It only says there was no response received from the server, for whatsoever reasons.

Secondly, [HTTP 502 Bad Gateway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502) means that the service you called *received an invalid response from the upstream server*.

Thirdly, in your specific case I see an Access-Control-Origin issue. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present) gets into details of how to solve it.

Comment: This is clearly not the answer to the asked question, but merely answers to somebody doing something wrong. I have the same situation and your answer (marked as resolved?) is no help, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

I usually do not subscribe in service, but in component. But this is my code in auth service.

```
getUser(userId: string) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const headers = new Headers({'Authorization': token});
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/user/' + userId, {headers: headers})           
        .map(response => {
            const data = response.json().obj;
            let user = new User (data.email, data.password, 
                                data.firstName, data.lastName, 
                                data.messages);
            return user;
        })  
        //.catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json()));
        .catch((err) => this.handleError(err));     
}
private handleError(error: Response) {
    if(error.status == 403 ){
        console.error(error + 'Session over. Please log in to continue.');
    }
    console.error(error + 'Session over. Please log in to continue.');
    this._router.navigate(['/']);
    this.logout();

    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || "Server error");
}
```

In my component, it should be:

```
this.http.getUser(string: string)
  .subscribe(
     result => { this.result = result;    
   }, 
     error => { console.log('raw error =>', err);
 });
```

Let me know if I could be more of your assistant.

Comment: Can you try error.status == 0 or error.status == 502

Comment: Like in my first comment (accepted solution) - this is not the right answer.